# Why the "print" buttons are disabled in my AltiumDesigner project?

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Here might not be the right place to ask but I couldn't find the proper place.

My problem is when I want to print a PCB the buttons are not clickable.

[image]
[image]

If I open print a schematic file, they work.

but they are gray if a PCB file is open.

why ?

Comment: Interesting. For me they work also in PCB view.
You could try to print it over Fabrication Outputs functions

Comment: That's why I wonder. I have printed many PCBs ago. and I used this version ,too. and they would be clicked then. but now . . .

Comment: The print options are not disabled for me either. Do you have a command open by any chance? And I have to ask, is this a legitimate copy of the software? If it's pirated, that's most likely the problem.

Comment: Right click on "HighVoltage.PrjPcb" In the "Projects" tab and click on "Project Options..." and then go to "Default Prints" and tell us about everything in this part.(an image would be helpful)

Comment: @derstrom8 . It's cracked but works with little bug. the thing is that "it worked before. but suddenly became so".

Comment: @Roh . the links: [pic1](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/56/cb3ca2935ea84cfed05575e0411f19e2/print1.png) [pic2](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/7/3270275a31528bf08c26be6e90d80c96/print2.png)  [pic3](http://www.uplooder.net/img/image/12/37433524f1504c22b08457f14aae8624/print3.png)

Comment: May have an obvious answer for you. When you went to print, which pane were you focused on? If you were focused on the "Projects" panel then it won't let you print. You have to be focused on the main project (editor window) panel. Let me know if this works so that I can post it as an answer.

Comment: @derstrom8. It's now working! I don't know why it got broken and also why it became right again. but I tested what you said. when I was viewing the PCB sheet I clicked the project name but the buttons are clickable all the time. now. the thing to know is why it became broken and then got right. I am confused.

Comment: See my answer. It explains in a little more depth why you were experiencing this. Let me know if you're still confused and I'll attempt to clarify further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious answer to me would be that you are not focused in the editor window. I notice in your screenshot that you have the "Projects" panel open. If you click on a window, it will "focus" on that panel (You will see the header change color slightly. Usually it is more gray when not focused, and a lighter color when focused). Here is what the top of the Projects panel looks like unfocused and focused:

Non-focused:

[image: Non-Focused]

Focused:

[image]

You can see the color difference in the header bar.

When you're focused in a panel other than the editor, you will not be able to print (you cannot print your "Projects" panel). This is the issue you were having--The print options were grayed out because they are not applicable to the "Projects" panel which you had in focus. When you click on the editor panel, it puts focus on it and the options will be enabled since you CAN print what is in the editor.